# Get "include fonts" setting from PowerPoint programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, powerpoint, office-interop

I'm developing MS PowerPoint addin in C# and I need to access the MS PowerPoint Save setting that tells whether to include fonts in the document (TrueType).

Comment: In Word you can simply use the [EmbedTrueTypeFonts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.embedtruetypefonts(v=office.11).aspx) property of your `_Document`. I couldn't find anything similar on the [Presentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.presentation_members.aspx) class, maybe it's hidden somewhere else.

Comment: please have a look at [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Check the documentation.  PowerPoint's SaveAs and SaveCopyAs methods both have an optional EmbedTrueTypeFonts parameter that controls this.

Comment: But it occurs to me that you might want to save the current presentation but rather to learn the setting for font embedding in the current presentation. You can look in the XML of the PPTX file; ppt\presentation.xml has a list of embedded fonts, and there'll be a ppt\fonts folder if there are embedded fonts and not otherwise. I don't know if there's any way to tell whether fonts will be embedded in a presentation that hasn't yet been saved. It looks like the default is not to embed unless the user or code directs otherwise.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg: When I'm programmatically using SaveAs, I'm not sure whether to use EmbedTrueTypeFonts or not (or mixed).I found out that there is an option in Save settings that checks whether the TrueType fonts are embedded (when user saves the document). So I'm about to check that setting and if it is checked then I will embed the TTFonts otherwise not. The only problem is that I'm unable to access the settings programmatically.

Comment: @roadrunner See my answer below;

Answer (score 1):

In reply to your most recent comment (as a answer rather than comment because it needs a bit more room and some code):

You may not need to worry about it; in my experience and after a couple more tests during our conversation, it seems that PPT retains the font embedding settings even after you've closed and re-opened the file.

For example, if I turn font embedding off (in File | Options | Save settings) then save the file, font embedding will be off for that file when I re-open it (even after restarting PPT).

Conversely, if I turn font embedding on and save, it'll remain on when I re-open the file and *HERE'S THE BIT THAT WILL BE OF INTEREST TO YOU* when I save again, the fonts will be embedded, including any newly added fonts. This also holds true if I Save As to a new file name.

So basically, if the file's been set to embed fonts, it'll continue to do so when saved.

Now in theory, you should be able to do something like this (and for each font, if .Embedded is true, set a flag to indicate that font embedding is going on).  But at least in 2010, it seems to be buggy. I'm seeing .Embedded return 0 (ie, False) whether the font's embedded or not.  Maybe I'm missing something (and if so, would welcome corrections) but it doesn't appear that .Embedded is reliable.

```
Sub ListFonts()
    Dim x As Long
    With ActivePresentation.Fonts
        For x = 1 To .Count
            Debug.Print .Item(x).Name & vbTab & .Item(x).Embedded
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```